# Generate dynamic flow-chart

Tags: c#, .net, components, flowchart, image-generation

We are looking for some code/component that can **create a flow-chart (image) dynamically**, preferably in .NET/C# (although a Silverlight/Flash-component that takes a XML/JSON-feed will also be fine).

For example we have a (business) quote that goes through te following steps before it becomes final:

> Requested -> Pending -> Ready for revision -> Under revision -> Final

And as an extra step there is the possibility to go from 'Under revision' back to 'Pending'.

So the component/code should draw something like this (where 'Under revision' would be the active status for this quote):

[Example chart http://www.wowtah.nl/flowchart-example.gif](http://www.wowtah.nl/flowchart-example.gif)
The reason that we are not just creating static GIF-images (and load the correct one on demand) is that these steps can vary per customer implementation of our product. So we're looking for a way of dynamically show the user the workflow steps that are configured for them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the information for the flowchart come from?  (What process modelling language do you use?)

Comment: From custom classes. We have WorkflowStatusses and WorkflowSteps (which have a StatusFrom and a StatusTo). The steps are added to a collection.

Comment: So what is the StatusTo of Under revision in the diagram?

Comment: there are two WorkflowSteps where Under revision is a From-status, and one where Under revision is a To-status

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Microsoft [MSAGL](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I built a workflow solution a while back and evaluated a number of diagramming controls, including the MindFusion control.  I settled on the Syncfusion diagram control, primarily for its ease of use for an end user (especially when drawing connections).

I'm using the WPF edition, but they make editions for ASP.Net and WinForms.  It has methods for exporting to images.

These are some of the components that I can remember evaluating; I'd recommend giving them a shot and seeing which you like best.

[Syncfusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/),
[NWoods](http://www.nwoods.com/),
[yWorks](http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html),
[Nevron](http://www.nevron.com/),
[EasyDiagram](http://www.easydiagram.net/)

Answer (score 1):

MindFusion looks like they have some good diagramming controls that may work for you:

http://www.mindfusion.eu/diagramming.html

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime there are also open source diagramming libraries that you can find on Codeplex and Google code.

A very deep one with many features and very flexible is

http://nshape.codeplex.com/

Perhaps easier to program but more limited in scope

http://www.dalssoft.com/diagram/